# Smooth functions on preimage of a regular value

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $f:M\to \mathbb{R}$ a smooth function, such that $0\in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular value. Then $f^{-1}(0)$ is a smooth submanifold, and we get an algebra map
$$
f^\ast:C^\infty(M)/(f) \to C^\infty(f^{-1}(0))
$$
defined by $f^\ast(g+(f)) = \left.g\right|_{f^{-1}(0)}$.
My question was whether this map is an isomorphism. It seems to me that this should be the case, so I was wondering if someone could help me out here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem + https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange_preparation_theorem should do it.

Comment: @Max Thank you!